# VBA - code optimiziation for copying specific range of columns multiple times

Tags: excel, vba, performance, loops, optimization

I have an excel calculation that completes one iteration in 10 columns (+1 column for space for 11 total columns per set). My intention is to copy this range of 11 columns a number of times (ideally 350 or more) using VBA. Each time the range is copy/pasted, that iteration of the calcuation references the previous set for a "cascade" effect.

I've pieced together some VBA code that accomplishes this task but is incredibly slow to process and it is difficult to tell if the calcuation is working as intended at the larger end of the iteration scheme. I added a status bar to track the progress and I have noticed that operation grinds to a halt after 100 or so iterations. I currently have the count set to 100 iterations because that seems to be the point where it struggles.

I've looked around on here for help before asking this and discovered the **Application.ScreenUpdating = False** trick but that doesn't seem to solve the issue.

How do I optimize what I currently have? Is there a better way to go about doing this?

```
Sub CascadeCopy2()

Dim i As Integer, x As Integer
Dim count As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

count = 100

For i = 1 To count
    With Sheets("Calc").Range("V3:AF250").Offset(0, x)
        .Copy
        .Offset(0, 11).PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        x = x + 11
        
        
    End With
        Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & i & " of " & count & ":" & Format(i / count, "0%")
    
Next i

Application.StatusBar = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Since you know the size of your origin and destination range, try copying data without using Copy and Pastespecial, but directly using `Sheets("Calc").Range("V3:AF250").Offset(0,x).value = Sheets("Calc").Range("V3:AF250").Offset(0,11).value`, because Copy uses the clipboard, which is incredibly slow

Comment: If you have quite a large amount of data in your workbook, disabling autocalculation at the beginning of your code may speed it up significantly. Just don't forget to enable autocalculation at the end.

Comment: @ENIAC disabling autocalc does speed it up significantly but the issue then becomes filling in the copied cells with actual values. When I turn autocalc back on, it takes forever to update all of the previously copied cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy a range repeatedly across a worksheet, you need to do a for loop. You can use the `equals method`, but you will have to do two actions to copy the formulas, see below.

```
Dim x As Long
x = 1
    For i = 1 To 299 'the number of times you want to copy, change as needed
        With Sheets("Calc").Cells(1, x + 32).Resize(250, 32)
            .Value = Sheets("Calc").Cells(1, x).Resize(250, 32).Value
            .Formula = Sheets("Calc").Cells(1, x).Resize(250, 32).Formula
        End With
        x = x + 32
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Turning off `Application.ScreenUpdating` is a good start.

Copy-Pasting huge amount of data in loops can become painfully slow, because copy-paste requires using the clipboard, which isn't very efficient.
Try accessing you range directly, using something like this:

```
Sheets("Calc").Range("V3:AF250").Offset(0,x).value = Sheets("Calc").Range("V3:AF250").Offset(0,11).value
```

You can then also use the same principle to copy formatting, or colors, or font size, etc, with the same template. For example :

```
Sheets("Calc").Range("V3:AF250").Offset(0,x).Interior.ColorIndex = Sheets("Calc").Range("V3:AF250").Offset(0,11).Interior.ColorIndex
```

You can easily adapt it to your needs.

Comment: I might be using it wrong but I'm trying to wrap my head around the syntax. 

`For i = 1 To count`
       `Sheets("Calc").Range("V3:AF250").Offset(0, x).Value = Sheets("Calc").Range("V3:AF250").Offset(0, 11).Value`
            `Application.CutCopyMode = False`
            `x = x + 11`

`Next i`

The code definitely runs better but his doesn't work like I intended. Intead of moving with each iteration, it pastes the values onto the V3:AF250 range. What would the syntax be to copy V3:AF250 but then "paste" that range to subsequent columns? Maybe I'm using Offset wrong...

Comment: @localvandal12 setting the destination range equal to the source range removes the formulas.

Comment: @localvandal12 to copy paste formulas use the same idea but with `.Formula` instead of `.Value`